# Kotlin Android Extensions bug in Android Studio Canary

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Does anyone have this weird glitch that came with AS Canary 16 that when you build the app all the references via Kotlin Android Extensions light up red and show compilation error.

Even though the app builds I loose all autocomplete on Views and auto import always deletes imports for methods that are called on views because it thinks that they are not used.

Clean build helps sometimes but not always. Can anyone suggest how to fix this irritating issue?

Comment: Yep, have this problem too. I experienced it in the 3.1 release version too, as well as in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, albeit not nearly as frequently. 3.2 canary seems to do this *constantly*. I suspect it's a bug with either IDEA or the Kotlin Android Extensions.

Comment: What tends to help me is pressing Gradle Sync button

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is an issue with Android Synthetics in Kotlin. There is an open issue with JetBrains for it. You can track it here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23908

The reporter states that he can simply re-sync Gradle and things go back to normal. This works for me some of the time, but often times I will have to close & re-open the entire project.  Rare occasions require actually quitting the IDE. Even more rare, I have to clear IDE caches. After all that, if I still have problems, I'll delete `.gradle/caches` and let everything re-sync & re-download.

Definitely a huge headache.